# H2 + openJPA + JPA + Spring + apache Camel Java DSL configuration in intellij

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, intellij-idea, apache-camel

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I have created an embedded H2 database and defined a table in it. My module has the JPA framework support applied. There is no spring.config xml used. I want to do the following - create a persistent H2 database on filesystem and make jpa camel component read from the database.

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="1.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="camel" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <class>com.workflow2015.database.model.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:./dtbase/MYDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=WARN, SQL=WARN, Runtime=WARN"/>
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My camel context gets injected with spring-boot, and I am able to run other camel components and EIP. The result that I want to achieve is the following:

```
from("jpa://UserEntity?consumer.query=select o from UserEntity o")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                 //do smthing with it
                }
            });
```

I have UserEntity autogenerated from my DB schema into POJO. I am using maven for dependencies and the pom file has all the required dependencies.

The issue:

When I run the application for some reason it creates another database("testdb") with unknown schema to me and does not use the information provided in the persistence.xml

```
2015-06-05 22:35:00,980 [main           ] INFO  EmbeddedDatabaseFactory         Creating embedded database 'testdb'
2015-06-05 22:35:02,138 [main           ] INFO  tainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Why is EmbeddedDatabaseFactory creating this phantom database instead of using the one that I have created?
Consequently I cannot use the entity that I have created and error is shown that it cannot find schema.

Comment: You likely need to setup a `EntityManagerFactory` with the name of the persistence unit, and configure Camel's `jpa` component to use that. The docs however often show how to do that in XML only, but its possible to do in Java code too: http://camel.apache.org/jpa